# How to implement pair-wise distance in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I was implementing the squared pair-wise eucledian distance in tensor flow but wasn't able to match it with sklearn library. I implemented it using:

> dist(x, y) = dot(x, x) - 2 * dot(x, y) + dot(y, y)

but wasn't able to get the functions to match. Does anyone know what might be wrong? Here is the script:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

def get_Z_tf(x,W,S,l='layer'):
    W = tf.Variable(W, name='W'+l, trainable=True, dtype=tf.float64)
    S = tf.Variable(S, name='S'+l, trainable=True, dtype=tf.float64)
    WW =  tf.reduce_sum(W*W, reduction_indices=0, keep_dims=True) #( 1 x D^(l)= sum( (D^(l-1) x D^(l)), 0 )
    XX =  tf.reduce_sum(x*x, reduction_indices=1, keep_dims=True) # (M x 1) = sum( (M x D^(l-1)), 1 )
    # -|| x - w ||^2 = -(-2<x,w> + ||x||^2 + ||w||^2) = 2<x,w> - (||x||^2 + ||w||^2)
    Delta_tilde = 2.0*tf.matmul(x,W) - tf.add(WW, XX)
    return Delta_tilde

def get_z_np(x,W,S):
    WW = np.sum(np.multiply(W,W), axis=0, dtype=None, keepdims=True)
    XX = np.sum(np.multiply(x,x), axis=1, dtype=None, keepdims=True)
    Delta_tilde = 2.0*np.dot(x,W) - (WW + XX)
    return Delta_tilde

W = np.random.rand(4,3)
x = np.random.rand(5,4)
S = 0.9

#x_tf = tf.constant(x)
#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances(X, Y=None, Y_norm_squared=None, squared=False, X_norm_squared=None)[source]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x_const = tf.constant(x)
    Z_tf = get_Z_tf(x_const,W,S)
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    Z_tf = sess.run(Z_tf)
    Z_np = get_z_np(x,W,S)
    #Z_sk = S*sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances(X=X,Y=W,squared=True)
    Z_sk = -S*euclidean_distances(X=x,Y=np.transpose(W),squared=True)
    #Z_sk = -S*euclidean_distances(X=np.transpose(x),Y=W,squared=True)

    print 'np'
    print Z_np
    print 'tf'
    print Z_tf
    print 'sk'
    print Z_sk
```

Result of the print statement:

```
$ python ../tf_playground/pair_wise_distance.py
np
[[-0.17742723 -0.57233957 -0.54851648]
 [-0.55742866 -0.76165072 -0.64532436]
 [-0.65967836 -2.20533905 -0.5111396 ]
 [-0.74866878 -0.47055669 -1.3993016 ]
 [-1.03158802 -2.17094844 -0.2506851 ]]
tf
[[-0.17742723 -0.57233957 -0.54851648]
 [-0.55742866 -0.76165072 -0.64532436]
 [-0.65967836 -2.20533905 -0.5111396 ]
 [-0.74866878 -0.47055669 -1.3993016 ]
 [-1.03158802 -2.17094844 -0.2506851 ]]
sk
[[-0.15968451 -0.51510561 -0.49366484]
 [-0.5016858  -0.68548565 -0.58079193]
 [-0.59371052 -1.98480515 -0.46002564]
 [-0.6738019  -0.42350102 -1.25937144]
 [-0.92842922 -1.95385359 -0.22561659]]
```

Comment: I don't know tensorflow and your example doesn't really seem minimal, but isn't something like `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` applicable?

Comment: @AndrasDeak does the numpy example seem minimal to you? If it does, the code is exactly the same and if you use the function at the top to compute the pair-wise distance, I don't think there is a smaller code to do it. If there is please share it with me.

The only difference is basically that one needs some placehoder/variable etc to hold data in tensorflow.

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes, I think that `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` should be applicable, though I chose to try it with sklearn, it should be the same (since to use sklearn's function one needs to import scipy). I will try it with that too now (cuz why not).

Comment: OK, sorry, after a cursory glance I failed to see that you included a numpy version. You're right, it's perfect as an example. And sorry, I know this is not the first time I'm bugging you about a minimal example:) At least in this case it definitely wasn't right.

Comment: You just forgot to use the `S` factor in your first two implementations, didn't you?:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Don't worry about it! I understand why you ask for minimal example and I agree. I always try to do that cuz it makes the question more useful to everyone and easier to get help with. Sometimes I fail to do it (my own incompetence) and sometimes I don't. Thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes you are right. omg I can't believe it. Thanks so much though. Please let me reward you for your help :)

Comment: Thanks, but this was essentially a simple typo (well, a mental kind), and I'm afraid it is unlikely to help future readers. So I suggest deleting your question instead. I appreciate the offer though:)